# Getting error while creating email campaign using EXM 3.4 in Sitecore 8.2.2

Tags: exm, ecm

I have configured EXM in Sitecore 8.2.2 and successfully able to send Email Campaign with Sitecore admin access. But for the **ECM Users** I am getting below error. Same is working fine in one of our environment with similar access rights.

Any idea on below issue (Extract from Sitecore EXM log)

```
14176 15:25:11 ERROR Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Exception: System.NullReferenceException
**Message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Source: Sitecore.EmailCampaign
at Sitecore.Modules.EmailCampaign.Core.ItemUtilExt.GetCampaignGroupPath(String campaignGroup)**
at Sitecore.EmailCampaign.Server.Controllers.Message.MessageController.Get(String messageId, String language)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer why this was not working. I have fixed this by giving the Read access of **Taxonomies > Campaign Group** to ECM users group.